# Getting a strange line underneath glyphicons and some images when inside <a>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a MVC 5 website using bootstrap and jquery. I am getting this odd line underneath some (not all) links containing images or glyphicons even though my css has text-decoration set to none. I even added inline styles to both the link and the img tag with no result...

```
<a style="text-decoration: none; margin-right: -20px;" href="/">
<img width="35" height="44" style="text-decoration: none;" alt="Fhlora Homepage" src="/Content/img/Fhlora_logo.png">
</a>
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle or a demo page where we can see this happening?

Comment: I'll try to see if I can get it to happen in a fiddle

Comment: It occurred to me in the middle of the night that I had not checked the image for artifacts. That was it. I feel kind of dumb for not checking first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in css

```
a:link { text-decoration: none; }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
a:active { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```